# Android studio emulator logcat different from physical device

Tags: android-studio

The logcat is showing a lot of empty processes

I'm just used to have a simple endless logcat from physical device where i can filter what i want, how can i achieve this with the emulator running? I'm currently seeing a lot of empty processes [image]